# How to show array in a list field of Sonata

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata

I have a CRUD created with SonataAdminBundle, everything works fine except when listing the existing profiles, they contain a "roles" field, which is composed of several roles and in the entity is defined as an array. Well, when you try to render the data obtained from the database, it throws an error where it indicates that it can not be converted from "array" to "string", the error is exactly the following:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

I have this **configureListFields**:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id', 'integer',
            array(
                'label' =>  'ID'
            )
        )
        ->addIdentifier('name', 'string',
            array(
                'label' =>  'Name'
            )
        )
        ->add('slug', 'string',
            array(
                'label' =>  'Slug'
            )
        )
        ->add('roles', 'array',
            array(
                'label' =>  'Roles'
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

The entity "Profile":

```
class Profile
{
 /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 private $id;

 /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @Gedmo\Versioned()
  * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
  * @Gedmo\Translatable
  */
 private $name;

 /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @Gedmo\Versioned()
  * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=120, unique=true)
  */
 private $slug;

 /**
  * @var array
  *
  * @Gedmo\Versioned()
  * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
  */
 private $roles;

 /**
  * @Gedmo\Locale
  */
 private $locale;

 public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
 {
     $this->locale = $locale;
 }

 /**
  * Constructor
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->roles = array();
 }

 /**
  * Get id
  *
  * @return integer
  */
 public function getId()
 {
     return $this->id;
 }

 /**
  * Set name
  *
  * @param string $name
  *
  * @return Profile
  */
 public function setName($name)
 {
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->slug = Tools::getSlug($name);

     return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get name
  *
  * @return string
  */
 public function getName()
 {
     return $this->name;
 }

 /**
  * Set slug
  *
  * @param string $slug
  *
  * @return Profile
  */
 public function setSlug($slug)
 {
     $this->slug = $slug;

     return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Get slug
  *
  * @return string
  */
 public function getSlug()
 {
     return $this->slug;
 }

 /**
  * @param $role
  * @return $this
  */
 public function addRole($role)
 {
     if (!$this->hasRole($role)) {
         $this->roles[] = strtoupper($role);
     }
     return $this;
 }

 /**
  * Remove role
  *
  * @param array $role
  */
 public function removeRole($role)
 {
     $this->roles->removeElement($role);
 }

 /**
  * @return array|Array
  */
 public function getRoles()
 {
     return $this->roles;
 }

 /**
  * @param $role
  * @return bool
  */
 public function hasRole($role)
 {
     return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true);
 }

 public function __toString()
 {
     return $this->name;
 }
}
```

And when I load the list in the browser, it shows me the error mentioned above.

I tried this too, and the result is the same:

```
->add('roles', 'collection',
            array(
                'label' =>  'Roles'
            )
        )
```

What should I do to show a String in the list and render the template correctly?

**NOTE: If within the configureListFields () method, I remove the "roles" field, everything works normally.**

Comment: How you want to display array as string type??

Comment: For example, if I get the following array:

    array(
        0 => 'ROLE_USER',
        1 => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
        2 => 'ROLE_GOD'
    )


I would like it to be displayed on the screen in the "roles" field as follows:

ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_GOD

Obviously you have to do a conversion to move from Array to String, and that is what I do not do from the form :/

Comment: I made a mistake, I did not say that the roles I get serialized ***

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom. If the list field is not working with the type `array` (though it should... if ugly), you might do better to add a method to the `Profile` to convert to a nicer string:

```
public function getRolesAsString()
{
    return implode(',', $this->roles);
}
```

Then in listMapper:

```
->add('rolesAsString', 'string', ['label' =>  'Roles'])
```

**EDIT: Misread, you meant list fields... this for the form - see above for lists**

You can use choice type with multiple allowed:

```
$roles = [
    'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin',
    'ROLE_USER'  => 'User',
    'ROLE_GOD'   => 'Hallelujah',
];

$formMapper
    ->add('roles', 'choice', [
        'choices'  => $roles,
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
    ])
;
```

I think by default this stores a serialized array string and transforms it back for the form.

Comment: The problem is that each "Profile" has different roles, and there are 1100 roles in total, so I need it to be totally dynamic since each case will return a different "roles" field since each profile has its own roles. I hope to explain myself correctly, my English is very bad, sorry.

Comment: I misread anyway and explained a form...! Updated for a solution for listMapper.

Comment: I made a mistake, I did not say that the roles I get serialized ***

Comment: You will get unserialized array - the above solution will convert them to comma separated string for the list field.

Comment: Yes, it will be the solution, but I expected that Sonata would come prepared for it and with some option the SonataBundle would do it automatically. Dreamer -.-

Comment: you've missed a comma in: implode(',' , $this->roles);